# Translate date ranges to date sequences in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have `table 1` that looks like the following:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| campaign  | start_date |  end_date  |
+-----------+------------+------------+
| campaign1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03 |
| campaign2 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-06 |
| ...       | ...        | ...        |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

I'd like to create `table 2` that looks like this:

```
+-----------+------------+
| campaign  |    date    |
+-----------+------------+
| campaign1 | 2020-01-01 |
| campaign1 | 2020-01-02 |
| campaign1 | 2020-01-03 |
| campaign2 | 2020-01-04 |
| campaign2 | 2020-01-05 |
| campaign2 | 2020-01-06 |
| ...       | ...        |
+-----------+------------+
```

Keep in mind that `table 1` is going to have `n` number of rows and will be added to on a regular basis. I'd like to schedule the creation of `table 2` using a scheduled query.

I've played around with `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY()` in conjunction with `CROSS JOIN UNNEST`. I haven't been able to find a way to do this elegantly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [How to] Translate date ranges to date sequences ...

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'campaign1' campaign, DATE '2020-01-01' start_date, DATE '2020-01-03' end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'campaign2', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-06' 
)
SELECT campaign, day
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date)) day
-- ORDER BY campaign, day
```

with result

```
Row campaign    day  
1   campaign1   2020-01-01   
2   campaign1   2020-01-02   
3   campaign1   2020-01-03   
4   campaign2   2020-01-04   
5   campaign2   2020-01-05   
6   campaign2   2020-01-06
```

> Update - use below in your real use case (above was just example with dummy data from your question for you to test)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT campaign, day
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date)) day
```

Comment: This answer has the same problem as @gordon's answer. The SQL will be run every day without my input, so I can't specify 'campaign1' or the number of campaigns.

Comment: this was just example for you - remove WITH statement  and use just query as in update section i will post in few sec here

Comment: glad it worked for you. consider also voting up the answer if it was helpful :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `generate_date_array()` and `unnest()`:

```
select campaign, dte
from (select 'campaign1' as campaign,  date('2020-01-01') as start_date, date('2020-01-03') as end_date
     ) t cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(t.start_date, t.end_date, interval 1 day)) dte;
```

Comment: This approach assumes that I know the campaign name and the number of campaigns a priori.  I am looking for a query that will generate this table for an unknown number of campaigns.

Comment: @EvanKaeding . . . This makes no such assumptions.  `t` is simply an example of your data.  This is pretty much the same as Mikhail's answer, just provided a bit earlier.

Answer (score 0):

One other approach is to create a 'calendar' CTE (or a table in your database) and then cross join and filter:

```
with cal as ( select dte from unnest(generate_date_array('2000-01-01','2050-01-01', interval 1 day)) dte),
tbl as (
  select 'campaign1' as campaign, cast('2020-01-01' as date) as start_date, cast('2020-01-03' as date) as end_date union all
  select 'campaign2','2020-01-04','2020-01-06'
)
select campaign, dte from tbl
cross join cal
where dte between start_date and end_date
order by campaign, dte
```